# MySQL: Delete Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got two tables: USERS on SENEVICA schema and wp_wsyija_user on Wordpress schema.
Senevica is able to delete, insert and update rows on Wordpress.wp_wsyija_user table 
and Wordpress is able to do the same command on Senevica.USERS.

Using Mysql Workbench I've created a trigger on SENEVICA.USERS:

```
USE SENEVICA;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_UTENTE_AD AFTER DELETE ON USERS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM WORDPRESS.wp_wsyija_user
WHERE OLD.PK_USERS = wp_wsyija_user.FK_USERS;
END
```

This trigger doesn't work right because I get the following error:
`Error Code: 1142. DELETE command denied to user 'SENEVICA'@'MYIP' for table 'wp_wsyija_user'`
However, using SENEVICA's MysqlWorkbench I'm able to delete rows on Wordpress.wp_wsyija_user .

MySQl Server is based on Amazon RDS.

Comment: provide info:
`SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE USER='SENEVICA' AND HOST='MYIP';
SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA' AND HOST='MYIP';
SELECT * FROM mysql.columns_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA' AND HOST='MYIP'; SELECT * FROM mysql.procs_priv WHERE USER = 'SENEVICA' AND HOST = 'MYIP';`

Comment: Hi Chad,
SELECT * FROM mysql.db: 
% SENEVICA SENEVICA Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y
---------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA'
% WORDPRESS SENEVICA wp_wysija_user root@MYIP 2013-09-06 10:22:49 Select,Insert,Update,Delete 
% WORDPRESS SENEVICA wp_wysija_user_list root@MYIP 2013-09-06 10:46:29 Select,Insert,Update,Delete

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM mysql.columns_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA'
NULL
---------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM mysql.procs_priv WHERE USER = 'SENEVICA'
NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
GRANT DELETE ON databasename.tablename TO 'SENEVICA'@'MYIP';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

EDIT:

how about :

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE USER='SENEVICA';
SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA';
SELECT * FROM mysql.columns_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA';
SELECT * FROM mysql.procs_priv WHERE USER='SENEVICA';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

In those queries You have special priveleges for tables/columns.... see if any query returns any row.

EDIT 2:

I have found also:

```
GRANT SUPER 
ON '<database>'.'<tablename/*>' 
TO '<username>'@'<host/connection/ip/%>';
```

Comment: Hi Chad,hi jaczes,
I've granted the privileges using user root and for any hosts because I'm using a mobile connection.

Comment: Hi jaczes,
I'm going to test your suggestion.

Comment: I'm especialy courious about `GRAND SUPER`

Comment: Hi jaczes,
I'm not able to grant SUPER using root for the same error: access denied.

Comment: Hi jaczes,
<pre><code>
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE USER='SENEVICA';